# What is a "reverse type" tsop?

Tags: terminology

I was looking through a [datasheet](http://65xx.unet.bz/ds/hm628128.pdf), when I noticed this sentence:

> TSOP package is suitable for cards, and reverse type TSOP is also
>   provided.

What is a "reverse type" TSOP? I am familiar with TSOP packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is shown on page 3 of the datasheet you linked to. It is not a difference in package, but a difference in pin arrangement. Compare the pins between the HM628128ALT and the HM628128ALR -- the pin functions are reflected. Page 2 indicates that the ...ALT version is "normal type" and the ...ALR version  is "reverse type".

Comment: This allows chips to be mounted on both sides of the PCB with a minimum of wiring congestion.